# SP2010 Add users from people picker to list as separate list items

Tags: 2010, development

I would like to add users from a people picker as separate list items to a custom list.
Following code only saves the last person in my peoplepickerlist

```
string users = ppUsers.CommaSeparatedAccounts;
char[] splitter = { ',' };
string[] splitPPData = users.Split(splitter);

 SPList SiteAccessList = newSite.RootWeb.Lists["Site Access Rights"];
      newSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

 for (int i = 0; i < splitPPData.Length; i++)
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginName))
                            {
                                string LoginName=loginName;
                                SPUser user = newSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser("SPTEST\\"+ LoginName);
                             SPItem newEntry = SiteAccessList.Items.Add();
                            newEntry["Title"] = "New User";
                            newEntry["Permissions"] = "Contributor";
                            newEntry["UserName"] = user.Name.ToString();
                            newEntry["UserEmail"] = user.Email.ToString();
                            newEntry.Update();                                    
                            }
                        }
                        newSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing some code? How does PPeople get created? You only create one newEntry object here, too, outside the loop. You might want to move that line inside the loop, just after the EnsureUser call.

Comment: Thanks James, that was the problem: SPItem newEntry = SiteAccessList.Items.Add();  Must be in my loop...